# Boolean was not saved correctly in sqlite3 in rails 3.1.4 when col created as BOOL in Firefox SQLite manager

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

There is a `canceled` column in table record in our rails 3.1.4 app. Initially the `canceled` was created in Firefox SQLite manager as BOOL which is a default type provided by the software. With `canceled = false` in rails, the `false` was saved into the record table for col `canceled`. The problem is when query with `Record.where("canceled = ?", false)`, the records with `canceled` as `false` were not selected because `false` is not interpreted as FALSE in sqlite3. In order to select all `canceled` = false, we have to do `Record.where("canceled =? OR canceled =?", false, 'false')`.

After we manually changed the data type of `canceled` from BOOL to 'boolean' in SQLite manager, the `Record.where("canceled =? ", false)` can pick up the newly created record with `canceled` as `f`. In SQLite manager, those `canceled` value is represented as `f` which is interpreted as FALSE by rails.

How to fix the table record (with 'false' for `canceled`) so that `Record.where("canceled =? ", false)` will work? Thanks so much.

UPDATE: when query the table record in rails console, the `canceled` does not behave as a boolean (either true or false). All records with `false` in column `canceled` can not be picked up by either `Record.where("canceled =?", true)` or `Record.where("canceled =?", false)`. But the .class returned for `canceled` is still `FalseClass` in rails console. Strange, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE my_table
   SET canceled = true -- or 1 check the table
 WHERE canceled = 'true'


UPDATE my_table
   SET canceled = false
 WHERE canceled = 'false'
```

**Edit:**

Try this

```
my_model.update_all( {:canceled => true}, {:canceled => 'true'} )
my_model.update_all( {:canceled => false}, {:canceled => 'false'} )
```

Comment: Did not work in SQLite manager. "SQLiteManager: Likely SQL syntax error: update lease_usage_records set canceled=false where canceled = 'false' [ no such column: false ]
Exception Name: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
Exception Message: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [mozIStorageConnection.createStatement]"

Comment: Yes, sorry it was SQL server syntax, just modify to fit sqlite

Comment: Query is the same on sqlite3.